# how to pass an image in function C#

Tags: c#, image, function

I need to pass an image value to a function, but I don't know which data type should I use?
I really appreciate your answers...

The typical function look like this:

```
void UserInfo(string userName, string userEmail,((image type? )) userImagel)
{

// code here

}
```

I am using Twitter API, after a successful logged in. I want to save the users info in a database using a function. SO they can import their profile information from twitter to our website.

in Default.aspx there is a line of code like this:

```
<img src="<%=profileImage%>" />
```

in Default.aspx.cs I used

```
public string profileImage=""; 
.
.
.
     profileImage = Convert.ToString(o["profile_image_url"]);
```

So by using that way the profile picture appears on the web page. it's obvious that it comes as a link (URL) . Now, how can I save that image from that URL in my database? and how to pass its value in a function?

Best Regards

Comment: (*Where* does the image come from, and what type does *that* have?)

Comment: The image come from Twitter account. (after a successfull login)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 Framework 4.0

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms, WPF, WinRT, WinJS, ...? How did you obtain the image? Is it a byte array, a URL, is it a file on disk?

Comment: it's URL from Twitter. I am able to retrieve user info using API.
I am using asp.net C#

Comment: And what do you want to do with it? All this info must be added to the question, otherwise we have no idea what it is you want to do; it is way too incomplete as it is and should be marked for deletion...

Comment: I am using Twitter API, after a successful logged in. I want to save the users info in a database using a function. SO they can import their profile information from twitter to our website.

Comment: Show the code that how your API gets the image? Is there a method which gets the image, so what is it's return type?

Comment: I added a lit more info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I would avoid storing an image binary in a database unless there is a particular reason to do so. In any case, as you describe it, you do not yet have an image, you have the image's URL:

```
private void UserInfo(string userName, string userEmail, string imageURL);
```

The question the, is what to do with the image.

If you want to obtain the actual image, you can download it with the `System.Net.WebClient`, for example:

```
private void UserInfo(string userName, string userEmail, string imageURL)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] imgData = client.DownloadData(imageURL);

    // store imgData in database (code depends on what API you're 
    // using to access the DB
}
```

There are more likely and scalable scenarios, though:

- You could store the image's URL in your database and use that in your web pages, letting Twitter serve the images (save you bandwidth).
- You could download the image (as above) and then store it on your web server's hard disk instead of the database. That way image requests can be handled by the web server instead of the database, which generally has quite a few advantages if your service grows (caching, CDN, ...)

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for... 
Good Job!Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
void UserInfo(string userName, string userEmail, System.Drawing.Image userImagel)
{

// code here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of your image file:

```
Bitmap bimage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Pictures\2765.jpg");
```

and pass this object through your function:

```
UserInfo("abc", "abc@yahoo.com", bimage);
```

To receive image:

```
void UserInfo(string userName, string userEmail, Bitmap userImagel)
{    
// code here    
}
```